# Where do I place GLib DLLs on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, dll, glib

I am using GLib in a Windows application. Where do I place the GLib DLLs? What is the "accepted" practice here? Do I use a shared location like C:\Windows\System32 or should I keep a local copy within my application folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the dll is being used for your application specifically, include it in the installation path for your application so that users know it is an associated, needed item for your application.